# Display resized image on .aspx webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to resize an image from a given path before it will displayed in a `<asp:Image>`-Tag on the webpage. Is there a way without first storing the resized image "thumbnail"?

greez marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've a blog post about resizing images in ASP.NET/C#. You can check it here:

http://mnour.blogspot.com/2007/12/image-resizing-using-c.html

Comment: very useful to resize an image without quality loss. It worked with a combination of your link and the the answer from Simon Thompson. This link below was also very helpful. [link](http://www.aspheute.com/artikel/20020225.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted could use a HTTP handler to do it - see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ImageResizeWithHttpModule.aspx

Comment: Not bad.. but I not so happy with VB.Net. Is there a solution written in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Could always point the img tag to an aspx page which reads in the image, resizes and writes the bytes to the response stream and settings the mime type